Azure Python Function V2 Programing Model not showing function even after Deployment in Azure
I wanted to deploy CRON Timer Trigger using Azure Function in Python. I tried to deploy it using VS Code.
Here are the steps I followed:
Step 1: Installed all the following prerequisites:

Installed Azure Core Tools v4
Have Azurite V3 Extension Installed.
Working in Python 3.11.8.
Latest version of VS Code in Windows
Azure Function Extension installed

Step 2: Created Azure Python Function with Consumption Plan
Step 3: Created a Function App with Python v2 Model
Used VS Code Azure Extension to create Function locally
Step 4: After doing required changes in default function code, I tried to deploy that using VS Code Azure Extension by selecting the required function app:
Deployed using following Azure Extension
Step 5: Checked for deployment status. In VS Code it is shown as successful. In Portal all files which are not ignored, are uploaded to the Azure Function Resource but it's not showing as a function.
Function is not showing up in overview
However I can see files successfully deployed in App File Section
Step 6: Also I have checked deployed Azure Function in VS Code but I can't see function.json under Function.
Cross checked in VS Code
My function_app.py looks like the following:
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import traceback
import uuid
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import time
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import inflect
import logging
######################################## VARIABLES ########################################
# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()
# Define authentication parameters for power platform datavese
tenant_id = os.environ.get('TenantId')
client_id = os.environ.get('ClientId')
client_secret = os.environ.get('ClientSecret')
resource = os.environ.get('Resource')

# Constants
MAX_RETRIES = 5  # Maximum number of retries
BASE_DELAY = 1.0  # Base delay in seconds for the exponential backoff
MAX_DELAY = 60.0  # Maximum delay in seconds for the exponential backoff
BATCH_SIZE = 1000  # Batch size for logging purposes
RATE_LIMIT = 6000  # Maximum number of requests per time window
TIME_WINDOW = 300  # Time window in seconds for rate limiting
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100  # Maximum number of concurrent requests

# Audit Management Table
AuditManagement = os.environ.get('AuditManagement')

# Endpoint    
odata_endpoint = f"{resource}/api/data/v9.2/"
# Date variables
date_today = datetime.utcnow()
# Prefixes
prefixes = os.environ.get("Prefixes").split(",")
# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Handle Error
def handle_error(exception):
    print(f"An error occurred: {exception}")

######################################## Fetch Token ########################################
def fetchToken():
    token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token'
    #print("app_registration_token_url :",token_url)
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'resource': resource
    }
    token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
    #print("token_response",token_response)
    access_token = token_response.json()['access_token']
    print("access_token : ",access_token)
    return access_token

######################################## Fetch Audit Management Table ########################################
headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {fetchToken()}",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
post_headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {fetchToken()}',
    'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
    'OData-Version': '4.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'If-None-Match': 'null'
}
def fetch_audit_management():
    logging.info(f'------------Table Records--------------------')
    try:
        full_url = f"{odata_endpoint + AuditManagement}"
        print("full_url : ",full_url)
        response = requests.get(full_url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            records = data.get("value", [])
            if not records:
                print("No records fetched for While Active")
                logging.info("No records fetched for While Active")
                return("No records fetched")
            else:
                logging.info("Records fetched for While Active")
                return records
        else:
            logging.info(f"Failed to retrieve records. Status code: {response.status_code}")
            print(f"Failed to retrieve records. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    except Exception as e:
        handle_error(e)
        return None  # Return None when an error occurs

 
app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.schedule(schedule="0 0 4 * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=False,
              use_monitor=False)
def amr_timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    start_time = time.time()
    # Log the start of Azure Function execution in hh:mm:ss format
    logging.info(f'timer trigger function executed at: {time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}')
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    else:
        try:
        ###### Comment : Fetching while active entity from  Table
            logging.info(f'\n\nFetching while active entity from Table')
            records = fetch_audit_management()

            # Iterating over entites fetched
            logging.info(f'Iterating over entites fetched from Table')
            for record in records:    
                logging.info(f'\n\nFetched Records: {record}')
        except Exception as e:
            handle_error(e)

    logging.info('AMR timer trigger function executed in %s seconds', time.time() - start_time)

requirements.txt
azure-functions
python-dotenv
requests
python-dateutil
inflect
tqdm

local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated as I want to test the deployment reliably.
I tried all the above-mentioned steps. The expected results is successful deployment of Azure Function.

Please provide your function code and local.settings.json.

Hi @PravallikaKV, I have updated the function code, requirements.txt and local. Settings.json above.

Does this answer your question? Azure Function App (Python v2) - blob_trigger function not showing after deployment

@PravallikaKV, I have tried all the steps you mentioned but the Function App is not showing in the portal as you can see in below comments

Hi @akseli,
I have reverified requirements.txt and all the environment variables. It has no such issues. I have also checked the configuration as well in the Portal. I will reverify by creating a new function app and check the deployment.

Hi @PravallikaKV , I tried what you asked for but same result .i also tried from fresh start but same. Do I need to make any code changes? Please let me know.

Create a sample Python Azure function and compare with the structure of the existing function.


Make sure you have added all the required application settings in local.settings.json.
Add Storage connection string as value for the    "AzureWebJobsStorage" setting.

"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_connection_string>"
  }
}


Make sure you have added all the environment variables in the Azure Function App.

host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}


Include all the required packages in the requirements.txt.

Create a new Virtual environment and activate with the below commands:


py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate

Install the packages with the command:
pip install -r requirements.txt


Run the function locally.

Deploy the function to Azure Function App(Consumption Plan) again with the command:
func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name>



Deployment Logs:

Getting site publishing info...
[2024-04-11T12:10:06.519Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
Uploading 5.88 KB [###############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '7b5c575a-0'.
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running oryx build...
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.11 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20230210.1, Commit: a49c8f6b8abbe95b4356552c4c884dea7fd0d86e, ReleaseTagName: 20230210.1

Build Operation ID: 65736983f855799a
Repository Commit : 7b5c575a-0ef2-43ba-b475-cbb121978b71
OS Type           : bullseye
Image Type        : githubactions

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  python: 3.11.8
Version '3.11.8' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...


Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot


Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.11.8' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8'...
Detected image debian flavor: bullseye.
Downloaded in 3 sec(s).
Verifying checksum...
Extracting contents...
performing sha512 checksum for: python...
Done in 7 sec(s).

image detector file exists, platform is python..
OS detector file exists, OS is bullseye..
Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8/bin/python3.11
Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
Removing existing manifest file

Running pip install...
Done in 5 sec(s).
[12:10:19+0000] Collecting azure-functions
[12:10:19+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
[12:10:19+0000] Collecting python-dotenv
[12:10:19+0000]   Downloading python_dotenv-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
[12:10:19+0000] Collecting requests
[12:10:19+0000]   Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
[12:10:19+0000] Collecting python-dateutil
[12:10:19+0000]   Downloading python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
[12:10:20+0000] Collecting inflect
[12:10:20+0000]   Downloading inflect-7.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
[12:10:20+0000] Collecting tqdm
[12:10:20+0000]   Downloading tqdm-4.66.2-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
[12:10:20+0000] Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1
[12:10:20+0000]   Downloading urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
[12:10:20+0000] Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
[12:10:20+0000]   Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (140 kB)
[12:10:20+0000] Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
[12:10:20+0000]   Downloading idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
[12:10:20+0000] Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
[12:10:21+0000]   Downloading certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
[12:10:21+0000] Collecting six>=1.5
[12:10:21+0000]   Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
[12:10:21+0000] Collecting more-itertools
[12:10:21+0000]   Downloading more_itertools-10.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
[12:10:21+0000] Collecting typeguard>=4.0.1
[12:10:21+0000]   Downloading typeguard-4.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
[12:10:21+0000] Collecting typing-extensions
[12:10:21+0000]   Downloading typing_extensions-4.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
[12:10:21+0000] Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, urllib3, typeguard, six, more-itertools, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, tqdm, requests, python-dotenv, python-dateutil, inflect, azure-functions
[12:10:22+0000] Successfully installed azure-functions-1.18.0 certifi-2024.2.2 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 idna-3.7 inflect-7.2.0 more-itertools-10.2.0 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 python-dotenv-1.0.1 requests-2.31.0 six-1.16.0 tqdm-4.66.2 typeguard-4.2.1 typing-extensions-4.11.0 urllib3-2.2.1
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8/bin/python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
Done in 0 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.
Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.

Done in 12 sec(s).
Running post deployment command(s)...

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
Writing the artifacts to a squashfs file
Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor
Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs, block size 131072.

[===============================================================|] 557/557 100%

Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
        compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments,
        compressed xattrs, compressed ids
        duplicates are removed
Filesystem size 2325.05 Kbytes (2.27 Mbytes)
        33.37% of uncompressed filesystem size (6968.27 Kbytes)
Inode table size 5860 bytes (5.72 Kbytes)
        28.89% of uncompressed inode table size (20286 bytes)
Directory table size 5651 bytes (5.52 Kbytes)
        36.05% of uncompressed directory table size (15675 bytes)
Number of duplicate files found 33
Number of inodes 631
Number of files 560
Number of fragments 47
Number of symbolic links  0
Number of device nodes 0
Number of fifo nodes 0
Number of socket nodes 0
Number of directories 71
Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
Number of uids 1
        root (0)
Number of gids 1
        root (0)
Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-kpyfn.zip located
Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
Resetting all workers for kpyfn.azurewebsites.net
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!


Hi @Pravallika KV,
I made the changes as you suggested for local.settings.json
{   "IsEncrypted": false,   "Values": {     "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=< >;AccountKey=< >",     "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",     "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"   } }
host.json is same. requirements.txt is also up to data. Function isrunning locally in a .venv environment. Also deployed with
func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name>
Functions in MyFuncApp:

Output I am getting is below:
"
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
[2024-04-11T13:03:48.886Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in Myfunction:
"
Getting blank in last line

Check function App in portal.

The function app is not showing in Portal. The App Files is showing all the necessary files deployed in the Azure Function Resource. I have tried this method multiple times.
I will retry the suggested methods with a new function app.
